# Creating a CSS blinking eyelid effect

Tags: css, css-animations, spinner, css-shapes

I am trying to create a wait/countdown screen that shows an eye along with the eyelid, and eyeball with an iris effect.  Given that so many of us spend time pointlessly staring at such spinners the effect I am trying to achieve is of the "eye" spinner looking back at the viewer and blinking.

```js
document.getElementById('waitDia').showModal();

var ticks = 300,
    ticker = setInterval(changeTick,1000);

function changeTick()
{
 document.getElementById('spnTick').innerText = --ticks;
 if (0 === ticks) clearInterval(ticker);
}
```

```css
#waitDia
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0 !important;
 top:0 !important;
 width:100vw !important;
 height:100vh !important; 
 padding:0; 
 min-width:100vw;
 min-height:100vh; 
 background-color:transparent !important;
}

#waitDia::backdrop{background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.2);}

#spnTick
{
 position:absolute;
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 top:0;
} 
#waitbox
{
 left:0 !important;
 top:0 !important;
 width:100vw !important;
 height:100vh !important;
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
}


#eyeball
{
 position:relative;
 top:-10vh;
 left:-6px;
 width:calc(24vh + 12px);
 height:calc(24vh + 12px);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:rgba(0,128,128,0.5);
 border-radius:100%;
 border:1px solid transparent;
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 18px 2px blue;
 z-index:99999998;
}


#waitsecs
{
 position:absolute;
 left:calc(50vw - 12vh);
 top:46vh;
 width:24vh;
 height:24vh;
 font-size:8vh;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 
}

#waitEye
{
 position:absolute;
 top:27vh;
 left:calc(50vw - 23vh);
 width: 46vh;
 height: 46vh;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
 border-radius: 100% 0px;
 transform: rotate(45deg); 
 mix-blend-mode:overlay;
 z-index:199999999;
 box-shadow:0 -0.5vh 0 2px #f1c27d,inset 0 6px 4px 4px black;
}
body,html
{
 background:black;
 font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<dialog id='waitDia' class='waitdia'>
   <div id='waitbox'>
    <div id='waitsecs'><span id='spnTick'>300</span><div id='eyeball'></div></div>
   <div id='waitEye'></div> 
   </div>  
  </dialog>
```

What I have been able to achieve thus far is shown below - I have set the ticker at 300 seconds here merely by way of illustration so it keeps working for a looong time - in the real application the wait time is likely to be considerably lesser.

While this effect is heading in the right direction it still lacks the eyelid blink effect.  I suspect that this is easily doable with the help of correct 'box-shadow' manipulation and a simple animation. However, here I hit the limits of my part time CSS skills.  I'd be most grateful to anyone here who might be able to suggest improvements to complete this implementation.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more realistic effect:

Comment: You are not asking for specific help with a specific question and, if anything, you are asking for opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this differently and consider rotation for the blink effect. The trick is to create the eye with two elements (the eyelid) to be able to blink it.

Here is the code with only the blink animation:

```css
.eye {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  perspective: 200px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% 250%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) top/100% 50%,
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% -150%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) bottom/100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat
}

.eye>div {
  height: 50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  animation:b1 0.8s  infinite ease-out alternate;
}
.eye>div:last-child {
  transform-origin:top;
  animation-name:b2;
}
.eye>div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:10%;
  right:10%;
  padding-top:80%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -5px 5px 2px 4px black;
}
.eye>div:last-child:before {
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -6px -4px 2px 4px black;
}


body {
 background:#000;
}

@keyframes b1{
  to { transform:rotateX(-88deg);}
}
@keyframes b2{
  to {transform:rotateX(88deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="eye">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Here is a more realistic blinking with a full eye:

```js
var ticks = 300,ticker;
setTimeout(function() { ticker = setInterval(changeTick,1600);},500);

function changeTick()
{
 document.querySelector('.eye span').setAttribute('data-text', --ticks);
 if (0 === ticks) clearInterval(ticker);
}
```

```css
.eye {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
  perspective: 200px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% 250%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) top/100% 50%,
    radial-gradient(circle 100px at 50% -150%,#f1c27d 99% ,transparent 100%) bottom/100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  position:relative;
}

.eye>div {
  height: 50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform-origin:bottom;
  z-index:1;
  animation:b1 0.8s  infinite ease-out alternate;
}
.eye>div:last-child {
  transform-origin:top;
  animation:none;
}
.eye>div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:10%;
  right:10%;
  padding-top:80%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#fff;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -5px 5px 2px 4px black;
  animation:inherit;
  animation-name:color;
}
.eye>div:last-child:before {
  bottom:0;
  top:auto;
  box-shadow:
    -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
    inset -6px -4px 2px 4px black;
}
.eye > span {
  position:absolute;
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  bottom:18px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%) translateZ(55px);
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:20% 20% 0 0;
  z-index:2;
  animation:b2 0.8s  infinite ease-out alternate;
}
.eye > span:before {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  height:45px;
  width:100%;
  content:attr(data-text);
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:45px;
}


body {
 background:#000;
}

@keyframes b1{
  to { 
    transform:rotateX(-170deg);
  }
}
@keyframes b2{
  50% {
    height:20px;
  }
  60%,100% {
    height:0px;
  }
}
@keyframes color{
  0%,40% {
    background:#fff;
    box-shadow:
      -2px 0 0 3px inset #f1c27d,
      inset -5px 5px 2px 4px black;
  }
  40.1%,100% { 
    background:#f1c27d;
    box-shadow:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="eye">
  <div></div>
    <span data-text="300"></span>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you - this answer comes closest to accomplishing what I originally set out to do so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

### SVG  solution

*Version without counter*

- Animation of the eyelid of the eye is achieved by changing the
  attribute "d"  by moving from the top to the bottom.
- For realistic image of the eyelid (giving volume) radial gradients
  are used.
- Pause animation in the upper and lower position of the eyelid is
  achieved by repeating the positions attribute `d`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="25%" height="25%"   viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
 <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="40%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="45%" fy="20%">
   
   <stop stop-color="#B7B3B8" offset="10%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDC9D0" offset="65%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#9D90A2" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDBED3" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
 </defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDG2U.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />

 <path id="veko" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="#B9B5BB" stroke-width="4" d="m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z" >
 <animate attributeName="d" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;    
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;
   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z"    />
 </path>
</svg>
```

*Variant with add countdown*

```js
var checks = 100,
    checker = setInterval(Count, 2100);

  function Count() {
    document.getElementById('txt1').textContent = --checks;
    if (0 === checks) clearInterval(checker);
  }
```

```css
.container {
 background:silver;
 
}
svg {
display:block;
width:15%;
height:23%;
padding-left:0.5em;
padding-bottom:1.5em;
margin:1em;
border-radius:50%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
background:#8C6282;
}
#txt1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  fill:#FFDD00;
  stroke:#917E00;
  text-anchor:middle;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container"> 

<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   width="50%" height="50%"   viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs> 
  
 <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="40%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="45%" fy="20%">
   
   <stop stop-color="#B7B3B8" offset="10%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDC9D0" offset="65%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#9D90A2" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="#CDBED3" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient> 
  <mask id="msk1" > 
   <path fill="white" d="M0.9 129.9C10.6 74.7 114.5 44.3 176.2 88.8c8 5.1 16.2 15.8 16.8 23.4C200 200 1.1 166.8 0.9 129.9" />
  </mask>
 </defs> 
 <g mask="url(#msk1)" >
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDG2U.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"   />

<text id="txt1" x="98" y="130"  >100</text> 

 <path id="veko" fill="url(#grad1)" stroke="#B9B5BB" stroke-width="1" d="m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z" >
 <animate attributeName="d" dur="2.4s" repeatCount="indefinite" values="
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;    
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z;
   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;   
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 6.4 4.9 6.4 4.9-0.1 0.7 2.8-0.5 0.4 2.1-4.7 5.2-11 10.6-17.4 14.6-6 3.8-12.7 6.5-19.5 8.9-6.1 2.1-12.4 3.9-18.9 4.7-8.3 1-16.8 0.5-25.2 0-13-0.8-26-2.3-38.8-4.7-15.6-2.9-46.2-11.9-46.2-11.9z;
   m12.7 132c0 0 25.6-19.6 39.8-27.1 11.7-6.2 23.9-11.9 36.9-14.4 10.7-2.1 21.9-2 32.6-0.4 8.5 1.3 16.8 4.3 24.6 7.8 9 4.1 17.1 9.9 25.2 15.5 2.2 1.5 4.9 2.6 6.4 4.9 0.4 0.6 1.1 2.4 0.4 2.1-6.7-2.5-17.2-10.3-26.1-14.8-6.6-3.3-13.1-6.8-20.1-9.1-5.2-1.7-10.6-2.9-16.1-3.4-8.6-0.8-17.5-1.3-26.1 0.4-12.4 2.5-24 8.4-35.4 14-14.6 7.1-42.2 24.6-42.2 24.6z"    />
 </path>
 </g>
 
 </svg> 
 </div>
```

Comment: even if I agree that SVG is more suitable for such thing, you should not add the SVG tag to the question because you change the author intent. someone else may also add the JS tag or the canvas tag and provide such solution which is not good. SVG is a great altenative (probably the best) but the author is mainly asking for CSS (related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366492/8620333)

Comment: @Temani Afif Quote from the [answer to meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366492/7394871) on the legitimacy of changing tags - "This is hard to cover generally; it's a case-by-case determination." Directly by the rules it is not forbidden to change,add  the tags in question.  Apparently this is why you replaced the `css3` tag in the header with` css`  Why in this case are you against adding the svg tag?  Further, from the answers to `Meta`, I realized that the right of priority in setting and changing tags belongs to OP

Comment: @TemaniAfif   Comment `@ Taplar` -
`It just my opinion that it's probably better to show users more questions related to their issue than not. Not all users know what they need` **And one more reason:** Answers to `SO` serve not one, specific user, but supplement the knowledge base.  Removing the tag `SVG` we deprive users who are looking for this tag to see these answers

Comment: CSS3 was always a non needed tag and people are confusing between versions. Actually we don't need CSS version, CSS is simply CSS and we recently made css3 synonym of CSS (related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385583/8620333) and I hope people will stop using the term CSS3. I am against adding the SVG tag because if the OP added the tag initially I would have never provided my CSS answer as I know CSS is not the way to go but the question was about CSS and the OP start coding this with CSS. SVG answers are here to proove that indeed it's a good alternative to consider.

Comment: quote from the meta question `Definitely do not add tags to questions just because someone answers with that language/library/framework.`. If the OP will later be convinced that SVG is the best alternative and will accept an SVG answer then I will add the tag but the question as stated is still about CSS. It's good to provide SVG, Canvas, JS solution as alternatives but adding the tag will make the other answers less relevant because people will say *why someone proving a CSS solution when SVG is the trivial one and OP asked for it since the tag is there??*

Comment: Thank you.  I have not accepted this answer since I really did want a pure CSS solution.  However, what you have suggested is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 2):

`SVG` + `JavaScript` version

Main idea is a moving of two control points of bezier curve to forme shape of eyelid depending from delta time between animation frames:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw(t) {
  circle.setAttribute('cx', Math.sin(t/1000)*2);
  grad.setAttribute('offset', 40 + Math.sin(t/3000)*20 + '%');
  t = Math.max(0, Math.sin(t/300));
  t = (t<.5 ? 16*t*t*t*t*t : 1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t)*6-3;
  let d = `-7 0C-2 ${t} 2 ${t} 7 0`;
  mask.setAttribute('d', `M-7 -7${d}L7 -7z`)
  eyelid.setAttribute('d', `M${d}`)
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-10 -10 20 20" height="90vh">
  <defs><radialGradient id="g1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
      <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%"/>
      <stop id="grad" stop-color="teal" offset="30%"/>
      <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
  </radialGradient></defs>
  <circle id="circle" r="2.4" stroke="black" fill="url(#g1)" stroke-width="0.2"></circle>
  <path id="mask" stroke="none" fill="white"></path>
  <path id="eyelid" stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
<svg>
```

Solution with progress and mouse move reaction

```js
let mouse = {x:0, y:0}, 
    progress = 0;
    
setInterval(e => progress = (progress + Math.random()/100)%1, 100)
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
addEventListener('pointermove', e => {mouse.x = e.x, mouse.y = e.y})

function draw(t) {

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  
  // двигаем зрачок
  let dx = mouse.x - innerWidth/2,
      dy = mouse.y - innerHeight/2,
      len = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy),
      ml = Math.min(len*10/innerHeight, 1),
      a = Math.atan2(dy, dx),
      x = Math.cos(a) * ml, 
      y = Math.sin(a)/2 * ml;
      
  circle1.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle1.setAttribute('cy', y);
  circle2.setAttribute('cx', x);
  circle2.setAttribute('cy', y);
  
  // процент загрузки
  let r = 1.8, 
      p = progress *2 * Math.PI, 
      px = r*Math.cos(p), 
      py = r*Math.sin(p),
      arc = 1-Math.round(progress);
      
  load.setAttribute('d', `M${r},0 A${r},${r},0,${arc},0,${px},${py}L0,0z`)
  load.setAttribute('transform', `translate(${x}, ${y})`)
  
  // анимируем градиент
  let offset = Math.max(0.2, (0.5 - len/2/innerHeight))*100 + "%";  
  grad1.setAttribute('offset', offset);
  grad2.setAttribute('offset', offset);
  
  // сглаживаем время по формуле easeInOutQuint
  t = Math.max(0, Math.sin(t/300));
  t = (t<.5 ? 16*t*t*t*t*t : 1+16*(--t)*t*t*t*t)*6-3;
  
  // кривая Безье в зависимости от сглаженного значения времени
  let d = `-7 0C-2 ${t} 2 ${t} 7 0`;
  mask.setAttribute('d', `M-7 -7${d}L7 -7z`);
  eyelid.setAttribute('d', `M${d}`);
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0 calc(50vw - 50vh); overflow:hidden;">
<svg viewbox="-10 -10 20 20" height="100vh">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="g1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%"/>
        <stop id="grad1" stop-color="#4f899d" offset="30%"/>
        <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <radialGradient id="g2" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%">
        <stop stop-color="black" offset="0%"/>
        <stop id="grad2" stop-color="#885d33" offset="30%"/>
        <stop stop-color="white" offset="100%"/>
    </radialGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <path id="load" fill="#fff"></path>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle id="circle1" r="2" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.2" fill="url(#g2)"></circle>
  <circle id="circle2" r="2" fill="url(#g1)" mask="url(#m1)"></circle>
  <path id="mask" stroke="none" fill="white"></path>
  <path id="eyelid" stroke="black" fill="none"></path>
<svg>
```

Comment: Thank you - although I am not accepting this as the answer I have upvoted it for its simplicity

Comment: @DroidOS thank you, i always try to write short-code answers

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById('waitDia').showModal();

var ticks = 300,
    ticker = setInterval(changeTick,1000);

function changeTick()
{
 document.getElementById('spnTick').innerText = --ticks;
 if (0 === ticks) clearInterval(ticker);
}
```

```css
#waitDia
{
 position:absolute;
 left:0 !important;
 top:0 !important;
 width:100vw !important;
 height:100vh !important; 
 padding:0; 
 min-width:100vw;
 min-height:100vh; 
 background-color:transparent !important;
}

#waitDia::backdrop{background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.2);}

#spnTick
{
 position:absolute;
 display:inline-block;
 width:100%;
 left:0;
 top:0;
} 
#waitbox
{
 left:0 !important;
 top:0 !important;
 width:100vw !important;
 height:100vh !important;
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;
}


#eyeball
{
 position:relative;
 top:-10vh;
 left:-6px;
 width:calc(24vh + 12px);
 height:calc(24vh + 12px);
 box-sizing:border-box;
 background:rgba(0,128,128,0.5);
 border-radius:100%;
 border:1px solid transparent;
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 18px 2px blue;
 z-index:99999998;
}


#waitsecs
{
 position:absolute;
 left:calc(50vw - 12vh);
 top:46vh;
 width:24vh;
 height:24vh;
 font-size:8vh;
 text-align:center;
 display:block;
 
}

#waitEye
{
 position:absolute;
 top:27vh;
 left:calc(50vw - 23vh);
 width: 46vh;
 height: 46vh;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
 border-radius: 100% 0px;
 transform: rotate(45deg); 
 mix-blend-mode:overlay;
 z-index:199999999;
 box-shadow:0 -0.5vh 0 2px #f1c27d,inset 0 6px 4px 4px black;
}
body,html
{
 background:black;
 font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<dialog id='waitDia' class='waitdia'>
   <div id='waitbox'>
    <div id='waitsecs'><span id='spnTick'>10</span><div id='eyeball'></div></div>
   <div id='waitEye'></div> 
   </div>  
  </dialog>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.